# Is it possible to copy things between two Virtual Machines using only the Clipboard?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, clipboard

Is it possible to copy things between two Virtual Machines using only the Clipboard?

Specifically: In VM 1 some blocks in a program are selected and CTRL+C. In VM 2 the blocks are inserted into the same program.

Not using files, specifically the clipboard.

What has to be fulfilled to make this work?

The VMs are different Windows VMs. VMWare Workstation 12.0.1

Answer (score 2):

No, VMWare workstation does not support clip-board sharing between VMs. See here for details: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/sharing-clipboard-vmware-35825.html

You can however share the clipboard between the guest and the host, so copying files from one VM, pasting to the host's desktop, cutting them, and pasting them to the second guest will work. likewise non-file content could be copied from one document to another on the host, and finally to a document on the destination VM.

Note that the VMs must have the VMWare Guest Tools installed in order to share a clipboard with the Guest.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of this, then you might want to supplement this answer with an automatic clipboard cleaner installed on the host. [Clipboard Fusion](http://www.clipboardfusion.com) is one of many.